# ¿Como hago que un input text acepte solo letras y espacios?

Tags: angular

Tengo un formulario reactivo en angular y quisiera saber como hacer para que los campos de texto solo acepten letras y espacios, por ejemplo para que ingrese un nombre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar RegExp, de la siguiente manera

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="return /[a-z, ]/i.test(event.key)" />
```

Comment: Hay que quitarle la coma

Comment: @user2930137 probando sin coma solo validaria letras, supongo que lo puso para valdidar espacios. Aunque tengo una duda, si se da el caso de que un nombre tenga la "ñ", no podria ingresarlo

Comment: El correcto es así: [a-zñ ]

Comment: Y como necesitas que sean nombres, lo más seguro es que quieras que usen tildes, minúsculas y mayúsculas. Entonces utiliza [a-zA-ZñÑá-úÁ-Ú ]

Answer (score 0):

Al ser un formulario reactivo puedes usara pattern

```
  changetitle: FormGroup;

 constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, ) {
 this.changetitle= this.fb.group({
  title: [null, [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('a-zA-ZñÑá-úÁ-Ú')]],
});
```

}